# After unkown update: lost all menus (dock, slingshot, upper bar, except for desktop files)

Tags: wingpanel, plank, updates, slingshot

I screwed up after an update (probably from a ppa of another distribution from which I wanted the internet browser...) so when I log in to the account, I only have the background image and the desktop files. No dock, panels, applications, etc. Tried to boot with the extra features to check packages and filesystem but it did nothing.

Any hint on how to revert this? I'm currently on windows (I have dual boot). ALthough i can access personal files, I have nothing to work with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the browser?

Comment: I added temporarily the trisquel ppa to get the icecat directly, I turned off the updates it showed but I guess at least one was kept :/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/questions/578258/i-cant-install-icecat-on-ubuntu-12-04 there is a warning about this ppa that it is for older versions of ubuntu.

To remove that ppa press CTRL + ALT + F1 while on the login screen and type your username and password to enter TTY.Type`sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/ toutatis-updates main"` and after that type  `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

After it is finished exit TTY by pressing  CTRL + ALT + F7 and reboot the system and login. Your installation should be running now.

If this doesn't work open TTY (do you remember :) and login then type `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`.After that type `sudo ppa-purge "deb http://mirror.fsf.org/trisquel/ toutatis-updates main"` and ffter that command is finished type `sudo apt-get upgrade` then press CTRL + ALT + F7 to exit TTY then reboot and login. Your ELementary OS should work now

Comment: I haven't seen reference to the TTY for a long time!
Thanks for the answer, hadn't seen any similar answer while searching for the problem.

Comment: I haven't seen reference to the TTY for a long time!
Thanks for the answer, hadn't seen any similar answer while searching for the problem. 

I did part 1 - no changes

I went for part 2 (and repeated to make sure there were no mistakes) and I got the following error:

`updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

`

Comment: continued output:

` E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored or old ones used instead.
Warning: apt-get update failed for some reason `

Comment: I tried to add the ppa it mentions that were not found but it says invalid (using `sudo add-apt-repository (...)`)

I checked again the methods you mentioned but I still get no changes

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is your system working now?

Comment: No, still the same after your recommendation. Still no menus (upper bar, slingshot, dock). On desktop I only have some folders left there. But i can access files and apps through the terminal

Comment: @AntonioS Try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
` to reinstall the elementary desktop (slingshot , etc)